# How to use UPDATE statement inside a SELECT statement in SQL Server trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-server-2016

Following is my trigger that I'm trying to do both insert and update based on the inserted record. I'm writing this `INSERT` trigger in my `EVN_UPTIME` table([db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HgF_iAFO)) when rows get inserted the trigger will sort out the records and insert into `ACT_UPTIME` table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tag_name] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [tag_id] [int] NULL,
    [tag_value] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [tag_timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [tag_quality] [int] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving',9,0,'2023-03-10 13:01:37.033',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO2.f_encoder_IS_moving',11,1,'2023-03-10 13:02:00.617',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO2.f_encoder_IS_moving',11,0,'2023-03-10 13:02:29.317',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving',9,1,'2023-03-10 13:02:52.733',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving',9,0,'2023-03-10 13:03:07.837',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving',9,1,'2023-03-10 13:03:08.320',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.CMM.Prgm_MainProgram.f_motor_start',13,0,'2023-03-10 13:04:11.203',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving',9,0,'2023-03-10 13:04:18.963',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.CMM.Prgm_MainProgram.f_motor_start',13,1,'2023-03-10 13:04:34.330',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO2.f_encoder_IS_moving',11,1,'2023-03-10 13:07:54.590',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving',9,1,'2023-03-10 13:08:19.947',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving',9,0,'2023-03-10 13:08:56.550',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM4.d_auto_mode',4,0,'2023-03-10 13:09:22.817',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.CMM.Prgm_MainProgram.f_motor_start',13,0,'2023-03-10 13:13:29.127',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.CMM.Prgm_MainProgram.f_motor_start',13,1,'2023-03-10 13:13:40.457',192)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVN_UPTIME] (tag_name, tag_id, tag_value, tag_timestamp, tag_quality)
VALUES ('AB.CMM.Prgm_MainProgram.f_motor_start',13,0,'2023-03-10 13:13:45.477',192)
```

```
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ACT_UPTIME(
        tag_id, 
        machine,
        down_start_time,
        down_end_time,
        total_downtime,
        create_user, 
        create_date
    )
    SELECT
        tag_id,
        CASE 
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM1.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N1'     
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM2.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N2'          
            WHEN tag_name = 'Fanuc.BS35X_SN002.AutoMode'  THEN 'N3'         
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM4.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N4'        
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.BS30_SN001.AUTO_MODE'  THEN 'N5'     
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.BS45_SN006.AUTO_MODE'  THEN 'N6'    
            WHEN tag_name = 'Fanuc.BS75_SN011.AutoMode'  THEN 'N8'          
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'SKB'         
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO1.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-1'        
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO2.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-2'     
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO3.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-3'    
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.CMM.Prgm_MainProgram.f_motor_start'  THEN 'CMM'          
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ELPH.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ELPH'         
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_HT1.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'HT-1'        
            WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_HT2.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'HT-2'     
        END AS machine, 
        CASE 
            WHEN tag_value = 0 THEN tag_timestamp
        END AS down_start_time,
        CASE 
            WHEN tag_value = 1 THEN tag_timestamp
        END AS down_end_time,
        0,
        SUSER_NAME(),
        GETDATE()
    FROM
        inserted
END
```

Following figure is what I'm getting based on the above trigger, [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qzuFpahP)

[image]

Now getting to the question, the following figure is my end goal. [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RVQ7jAdG)

[image]

Following is the code for the SQL trigger what I was able to try out and got stuck at currently while figuring out my end goal.

```
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ACT_UPTIME(
        tag_id, 
        machine,
        down_start_time,
        down_end_time,
        total_downtime,
        create_user, 
        create_date
    )
    SELECT
        tag_id,
        CASE WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM1.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N1'     
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM2.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N2'          
       WHEN tag_name = 'Fanuc.BS35X_SN002.AutoMode'  THEN 'N3'         
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM4.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N4'        
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.BS30_SN001.AUTO_MODE'  THEN 'N5'     
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.BS45_SN006.AUTO_MODE'  THEN 'N6'    
       WHEN tag_name = 'Fanuc.BS75_SN011.AutoMode'  THEN 'N8'          
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'SKB'         
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO1.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-1'        
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO2.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-2'     
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO3.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-3'    
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.CMM.Prgm_MainProgram.f_motor_start'  THEN 'CMM'          
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ELPH.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ELPH'         
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_HT1.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'HT-1'        
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_HT2.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'HT-2'     
        END AS machine, 
        CASE WHEN tag_value = 0 THEN tag_timestamp
        END AS down_start_time,
        UPDATE [MES_DEV].[dbo].[ACT_UPTIME] 
        SET down_end_time =  
        (CASE WHEN tag_value = 1 THEN tag_timestamp)
        
        END,
        0,
        SUSER_NAME(),
        GETDATE()
    FROM
        inserted
END
```

Here I was trying to write a `UPDATE` statement inside a `CASE` statement when the trigger sees the `INSERT` record with the `tag_value` of `'1'` then the record with same `tag_id` which has `NULL` `down_end_time` value will be updated with the time, and finally calculate the `total_downtime` by getting the difference of the `down_start_time` and `down_end_time` times.

Somehow I'm getting bunch of syntax errors in SQL Server and not able to save the trigger.

What am I doing wrong here trying to write the `UPDATE` statement inside a `CASE` statement of the `INSERT` trigger? Is it not possible to do?

Comment: *"Somehow I'm getting bunch of syntax errors in SQL Server and not able to save the trigger."* What are those errors? Looking at your query, it looks like you have an `UPDATE` in the middle of a `SELECT` statement? That isn't allowed.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near UPDATE, Incorrect syntax near END, etc.

Comment: If you want to do an `UPDATE` that *must* be a separate statement. You can't just dump a different statement in the middle of another one.

Comment: @Larnu should I have a different `INSERT` trigger in that case or did you mean separate `UPDATE` statement inside the same `INSERT` trigger?

Comment: You can have *one* `AFTER INSERT` trigger, but if you want to do an `UPDATE` and an `INSERT` within that trigger you need both an `UPDATE` and an `INSERT` statement; you can't just "mash them together". `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...; UPDATE ... FROM ...;`

Comment: @Larnu understood, thank you very much for the clarification, I will try using that valuable info. and update my question if I find the answer.

Comment: Is the problem even simpler? Are you trying to create a trigger with a batch that starts `AFTER INSERT`? The syntax errors suggest you possibly simply forgot the `CREATE TRIGGER dbo.<triggername> ON dbo.<tablename>` part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do is doable *from a trigger*. what happens if there are two separate inserts. one with start and one with enddate. trigger doesn't look into the future. The only thing you can do is to check in the trigger if it's start row or end row. For start rows, you do insert, for end rows, you go to the log table and update the already started row to the ended row

Comment: ...could be done with instead of insert too, since an insert could contain rows of both type, so you could update any existing rows with end date, combine rows in inserted that have both, and insert new rows that only have start date.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer with the hints/clues provided by @Larnu in the comments section. Much appreciated for diverting me towards the correct side.

Here's to anyone finds it interesting :

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ACT_UPTIME(
        tag_id, 
        machine,
        down_start_time,
        total_downtime,
        create_user, 
        create_date
    )
    SELECT
        tag_id,
        CASE WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM1.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N1'     
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM2.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N2'          
       WHEN tag_name = 'Fanuc.BS35X_SN002.AutoMode'  THEN 'N3'         
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.NOR_CTMS.Prgm_NORM4.d_auto_mode'  THEN 'N4'        
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.BS30_SN001.AUTO_MODE'  THEN 'N5'     
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.BS45_SN006.AUTO_MODE'  THEN 'N6'    
       WHEN tag_name = 'Fanuc.BS75_SN011.AutoMode'  THEN 'N8'          
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_SKB.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'SKB'         
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO1.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-1'        
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO2.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-2'     
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ALO3.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ALO-3'    
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.CMM.Prgm_MainProgram.f_motor_start'  THEN 'CMM'          
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_ELPH.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'ELPH'         
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_HT1.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'HT-1'        
       WHEN tag_name = 'AB.HT_CTMS.Prgm_HT2.f_encoder_IS_moving'  THEN 'HT-2'     
        END AS machine, 
        CASE WHEN tag_value = 0 THEN tag_timestamp
        END AS down_start_time,
        0,
        SUSER_NAME(),
        GETDATE()
    FROM
        inserted;

    UPDATE A
    SET A.down_end_time =
    CASE WHEN i.tag_value = 1 
        THEN i.tag_timestamp
        END
    FROM ACT_UPTIME A INNER JOIN inserted i ON A.tag_id = i.tag_id
    WHERE A.tag_id = i.tag_id AND A.down_end_time IS NULL;
        
END
```